# npm ERR! missing script build

Tags: npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server, npm-scripts, npm-start

I'm using Windows 10 and powershell, trying to run a webpack app cloned from my github.

When I type `npm run start` I get:

> `npm ERR! missing script: build;`

The build script is most definitely in my package.json:

```json
"scripts": {
  "build": "webpack --mode development",
  "start": "npm run build; webpack-dev-server --open",
  "lint": "eslint src/*.js",
  "test": "karma start karma.conf.js"
},
```

When I'm on a mac, `npm run start` opens a local dev server just fine.

Any ideas why I am unable to run this on my pc? I am a rookie programmer. Answers written in plain English will be greatly appreciated.

The github repo with this project's config files:

https://github.com/GreanBeetle/api-project

I am happy to post the run log as well.

Comment: Please don't post code as images. Copy the code to the question instead.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Powershell, but is the meaning of `;` in powershell the same that in bash? If not, I suggest to replace it with `&&`

Comment: Yes I ran npm install first thing

Comment: I found the answer. You have to run this in the root folder of your directory. (Or wherever your webpack.config file is stored.) `node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server`

Comment: @John, I also had the same issue. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

In the root folder of your directory (or in whichever folder your webpack.config file is stored) run:

`node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server`

This gives command line access to the `npm run start` command

For further information:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-dev-server