# To make Angular 7 application seo compatible

Tags: angular, seo, angular7

[Html missing loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3q6g.png)

This creates problems in terms of seo 
How can I fix ?

Comment: can you explain bit more?

Answer (score 1):

Use angualr universal in your application to make your app SEO friendly

run below command on your root:

```
ng add @ng-toolkit/universal
```

Next, when you run your application by ng serve command you need to run below command:

```
npm run build:prod
npm run server
```

Now check the view source in your browser you can find HTML with SEO content like below:
[image]

Comment: npm run build:prod    

npm ERR! missing script: build:prod
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Did you mean this?
npm ERR!     build

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:


what is this error

Comment: you can try npm run build -- prod or npm run build:ssr or you can refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49470273/npm-err-missing-script-build

Comment: optimized means?

Comment: the changing thing didn't happen :(

Comment: npm run build:prod should run your application, try to search for that error

Comment: reinstalled with command  "ng add @ng-toolkit/universal --http false "
npm run build:prod npm run build: prop, failed at the last moment

new error

Comment: ERROR in src\app\app.module.ts(169,7): Error during template compile of 'AppModule'
  Could not resolve src/shared/confirm-equal-validator.directive relative to [object Object]..
src/app/home/stream-videos/stream-videos.component.ts(3,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/services/router.service'.
src/app/home/stream-videos/stream-videos.component.ts(5,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/models/Twchannel'.

Comment: It seems your application error, go to that line!! and check

Comment: no error, "ng build --prod" works fine.
"npm run build: prod" does not work

Comment: Please try to update angular CLI and npm also check for node